# Board / Card game expressions

Tags: words, terminology

I wanted to talk about a board game recently, and realized that I am missing all related vocabulary. Before you shout foul and throw dictionaries at me, these expressions are very difficult to look up, because most of them use existing words in new contexts. And I cannot ask the native Japanese I know, because they don't know the english terminology either. I'll make a list, and possibly add more to it if some are suggested. I am basically looking for the vocabulary to be able to explain any board game to someone.

**General**

> - Take a turn ("Your turn!", ...)
> - Passing a turn.
> - Token. (Many games have tokens, be it for money, health, victory points and so on)
> - Piece, as in Chess.
> - [Some statistic] meter / counter. (Threat meter?)
> - Pick a card/miniature/faction/... randomly.

**Words I have seen often, but which are made up to begin with**

> - Victory Point.

**Cards**

> - Draw a card.
> - Discard a random card.
> - Discard a card of your choice.
> - A deck of cards.
> - The correct expression for "hand".

**Dice**

> - Throw dice, or roll dice.
> - Reroll dice.
> - Count the sixes. (or any other)
> - Non-6-sided dice, in english usually called d8, d12 or d20.

Comment: The [Eijiro DB](http://www.alc.co.jp/) is really good for stuff like this.

Comment: @kdansky: I agree with Dave. But if you clean your question and narrow it down to the most problematic terms, it might get more acceptable to the site standards. Search all of those expressions and if you still have some you can't translate, come back here and show us your searching progress.

Comment: I put everything here on purpose including those that I actually know already. Having partial answers will annoy the next person looking for this immensely. If you take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language-usage it should be clear that the quality is fine, but the quantity is horrible. 3.5 daily questions is the result of the impossibly high standards. If I remove 80% of the examples, it's "cleaner", and less useful.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with asking this question. The faq says "ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". This is an actual problem the OP faces, and it's relating to the use of the Japanese language.

Comment: @Flaw You're right, but you're missing a point. Stackexchange sites are not a searching service like Google. It's a place where you ask problems you can't solve by yourself, let's say. Otherwise also posting a N-pages text asking to translate all of it would be legit too. :)

Comment: @Kdansky Ok, but your question is too broad like this. If you want you can answer your own question, including the ones you know and leaving the rest to be answered by someone else. I guess you can do it.

Comment: @DaveMG My comment was because of the -1 the question initially received. I do not think it deserved a downvote in such a short amount of time.

Comment: @DaveMG No there isn't. It's about personal preference. Everyone is free to vote according to his/her judgement. Just that I tend to believe in giving more leeway. It's not absolutely wrong to downvote, it's a way to let the asker know that there might be something that needs improving. But I'm worried that a high propensity to downvote will inhibit questions and answers. So if something is "not good", it gets a no-vote instead of downvote. Only if something is really "bad", then it gets a downvote from me. I distinguish "not good" from "bad".

Comment: @Flaw I didn't down-vote this question, but if you put your mouse over the "down-vote button", you'll see that its description says "This question does not show any research effort; it is bla bla". Note that it says "*does not show*" which means that maybe the OP did some research, but we can't know because there's nothing about it in the question.

Comment: @Alenanno If we are breaking the criteria down based on the description. Then we have 3. "research effort", "clarity", and "usefulness". I felt that it was not bad enough to warrant a downvote. But this is just my opinion. I just feel that we should have a encouraging-good-posts attitude rather than a discouraging-bad-posts attitude.

Comment: @Flaw I was just trying to explain why it was probably down-voted, I can't answer that completely since I didn't. :D I think that we should encourage a "down-vote and comment" behavior. So that the OP or the answerer can improve their posts. After that the down-vote might even be removed, since it can be done after an edit.

Comment: I quickly lost the motivation to improve the question when I saw how much bile I had to face. This comment thread is now multiple pages long and still utterly pointless. The grown up stackoverflow way would be to ignore the question or even answer it to get it off the main page. The elitists way is to argue endlessly over tiny rule differences. I will now vote for closing and deletion. Ideally, someone else will not be able to find this answer in the future, and be annoyed, then you got what you strove for with so much effort: Someone was prevented from learning.

Comment: Maybe you can consult http://ja.boardgamearena.com/ but they're mostly machine translation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### General

- Turn ("Your turn!", ...)　→　あなたの番【ばん】　・　出番【でばん】 ・　ターン　([俺のターン！](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%A4%BA%A4%C3%A4%C8%B2%B6%A4%CE%A5%BF%A1%BC%A5%F3)）
- Take a turn → （ターンを）行【おこな】う
- Passing a turn.　→　パス
- Token. (Many games have tokens, be it for money, health, victory points and so on)　→　トークン<sup>1</sup>　・　硬貨【こうか】？
- Piece, as in Chess.　→　駒【こま】
- [Some statistic] meter / counter. (Threat meter?)　→　？
- Pick a card/miniature/faction/... randomly.　→　ランダムに（・無作為【むさくい】に）取【と】る　・　選【えら】ぶ

### Words I have seen often, but which are made up to begin with

- Victory Point.　→　点【てん】　・　得点【とくてん】　・　勝利点【しょうりてん】<sup>1</sup>

### Cards　（カード）

- Draw a card.　→　カードを（X枚【まい】）取【と】る　・　引【ひ】く
- Discard a random card.　→　カードをランダムに捨【す】てる　・　捨【す】て札【ふだ】（に）する
- Discard a card of your choice.　→　｛捨【す】てたいだけ　・　勝手【かって】に　・　選【えら】んで｝捨【す】てる
- A deck of cards.　→　デッキ　・　山札【やまふだ】
- A hand of cards.　→　手札【てふだ】
- Discard pile. →　捨【す】て札【ふだ】置【お】き場【ば】　・　捨【す】て札【ふだ】の山【やま】
- Play a card　→　カードを出す

### Dice　（さいころ（賽子・骰子） or ダイス)

(*usually サイコロ in katakana*)

- Throw dice, or roll dice.　→　サイコロを振【ふ】る　・　振【ふ】り出【だ】す　・　投【な】げる
- Reroll dice.　→　再【ふたた】び（サイコロを）振【ふ】る　・　振【ふ】り出【だ】す
- Count the sixes. (or any other)　→　6をまとめる　・　揃【そろ】える ?　(educated guess)
- Non-6-sided dice, in english usually called d8, d12 or d20.　→　ｎ面【めん】ダイス (*usu. not サイコロ*)

### Coins （コイン）

- Flip a coin → コインを投【な】げる
- Heads → 表【おもて】
- Tails → 裏【うら】

---

<sup>1</sup> [ドミニオン](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8B%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3_%28%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%29)より

Comment: 骰子 or 賽子 apparently, though I don't know which one is the more common. My IME also failed me.

Comment: I think the latter is more common.

Comment: Can I use 駒 for pieces in other games too? Or is that very specific for chess?

Comment: 駒 generically means "piece".  Actually each chess piece probably has its own name like in English, but I don't know what they are.　　将棋【しょうぎ】, being similar to chess, also had different names for each piece.  http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%86%E6%A3%8B

Comment: (I added a few things, since the answer was made community wiki. Hopefully this is okay. I'll add more as I come across them.)

Comment: @Hyperworm It is okay, yes. Actually it's what you're supposed to do with Community Wikis I think :D